# Example of __strong usage in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, strong-references

I was reading about __strong reference and __weak reference usage here: [Explanation of strong and weak storage in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262535/explanation-of-strong-and-weak-storage-in-ios5)

I tried writing a bit of code to demonstrate this knowledge. However, the __strong did not keep the object in memory as it was released. 
1st I did this:

```
Parent *  fumu = [[Parent alloc] init]; 
[fumu release];
```

Everything works as expected. Parent object init gets called, When released, the dealloc gets called.

2nd I did this:

```
Parent *  fumu = [[Parent alloc] init]; 
[fumu retain];
[fumu release];
```

The Parent object init method was called. But dealloc was not called because the Parent object that fumu references still has retain count of 1. As expected.

Using __strong

As stated:

```
**Strong: "keep this in the heap until I don't point to it anymore"
Weak: "keep this as long as someone else points to it strongly"**
```

Now let's say I use __strong keyword. If I add another strong reference like below, the Parent object should NOT call dealloc because we still have a strong reference (anotherFumu) to it. However, when I run it, the dealloc gets called. I do not see the strong reference having any effect.

```
Parent *  __strong fumu = [[Parent alloc] init]; 
Parent *  __strong anotherFumu = fumu;  
[fumu release];  //Parent object dealloc gets called
```

Please advise. thanks

**Result:**

I turned on ARC, and simply used nil to point the strong pointers away from the Parent object, and thus be able to correctly see the behavior of __strong and __weak like so:

```
Parent * fumu = [[Parent alloc] init];
__strong Parent * strongFumu = fumu;
__weak Parent * weakFumu = fumu;

fumu = nil; //your auto variables window should show that both trongFumu and weakFumu are still valid with an address
NSLog(@"weakFumu should be valid here, because strongFumu is still pointing to the object");

strongFumu = nil; //when strongFumu points away to nil, weakPtr will then also change to nil
NSLog(@"weakFumu should be nil here");
```

Comment: `strong` and `weak` are useful with ARC code, not MRC code.

Comment: Turn-on ARC! You can't write `retain` and `release` with ARC enabled.

Comment: @Cy-4AH -  I turned off ARC because I wanted to demonstrate __strong and __weak with code. All the examples I see of strong and weak are with properties.

Comment: @rtsao, like you noticed: `__strong` and `__weak` have no effect in MRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alloc` is short for allocate so when you call
`Parent *  fumu = [[Parent alloc] init];`
  you allocate the object so its retain count is =1 then you call `[fumu retain];`
your objects retain count is up to +2
then when you call `[fumu release];`
 it adds -1 so your final count will be +1 so that is right.

Strong and Weak are ARC types, you cant use them in non-ARC projects. And it is used with properties/variables... You would want to use `strong` when you need to own the object, you are already "owning" the object when you create the object in your example...

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW1

Comment: ok, so __strong/__weak or strong/weak types are only used with @property ? 

that means I can't do this?
__strong MyClass * ptr = ....

IF we can use them in that fashion, can you give an example?

Comment: @rtsao No, `strong` and `weak` are not just for properties. But they are just for ARC, not MRC.

Comment: @rmaddy got it, can you give an example for such usage? thanks

Comment: @rtsao Do a search here on `__weak` and `__strong` and you will find many examples.