# When to use strong, weak, retain etc?

Tags: objective-c

I'm porting a small C++ app to OSX and it's going well but one thing I don't understand are:

strong, weak, retain keywords in Objective-C around properties and in what situations I should use them.  We don't have these same concepts in C++.

Could someone please explain what they are and how they work because I've searched and what I've not found any good explanations of when to use them.
All I know is they relate to reference counting.  But that's it.

Currently, I've just put strong everywhere.  But I suspect I shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: See also: [Explanation of strong and weak storage in iOS 5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9262535)

Comment: Thanks, I also just found this great resource which explains it really well with examples.  Finally some examples! :)  http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties