# Benefits of using Weak variable instead of strong

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Can anyone provide me link or information about :

why `weak` variable is beneficial as compared to strong variable?

and `IBOutlets` in `ARC`, that should be `weak` or `strong`? Why delegate is also defined as weak property?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262535/explanation-of-strong-and-weak-storage-in-ios5

Comment: Why delegate is also being declared as weak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strong: assigns the incoming value to it, it will retain the incoming value and release the existing value of the instance variable

weak: will assign the incoming value to it without retaining it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW3

Answer (score 0):

The weak like the world is weak retain to object, when it dealloc that will be nil, and we can avoid the retain cycle. IBOutlets property because the view had retain it so that needn't strong retain it again.

Answer (score -2):

The current recommended best practice from `Apple` is for `IBOutlets` to be **strong** unless **weak** is specifically needed to avoid a `retain cycle`.

In general you should make your outlet **strong**, especially if you are connecting an outlet to a `subview` or to a constraint that's not always going to be retained by the `view hierarchy`. The only time you really need to make an outlet **weak** is if you have a `custom view` that references something back up the view hierarchy and in general that's not recommended.

Comment: Do you have a pointer to Apple's current recommendation?  When you use IB to create the outlet, I believe it defines it as weak.

Comment: IBOutlet should be strong, for performance reason...https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/storyboard-strong-iboutlet-scene-dock/?doing_wp_cron=1465817938.3935289382934570312500

Comment: That blog post is wrong.  The documentation it links to states clearly that declared properties should be `weak`.  The blog writer is promoting a premature optimization (avoiding the clearing of weak references), and is a poor programmer.  Don't listen to him.

Comment: OK.. thanks alot @Avi.. for giving me such a golden information...thanks..!