# How do I pass data from a text field in Flipsideview to Mainview? ios 7 xcode5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm currently writing an iPhone app that needs to pass data from a text field on the Flipside view to the Main view when the user clicks the Done button.  This is the last component of a project that I am working on.

I've tried including my `MainViewController.h` file on my `FlipsideViewController.m` file, and this doesn't work.  I'm currently writing in the - `(IBAction)done:(id)sender` portion, something like

```
MainController._aTextFieldOnTheMainView.text = _aTextFieldOnTheFlipsideView.text;
```

but I always get this error: `Property '_aTextFieldOnTheMainView' not found on object of type 'MainViewController'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change/remove your `weak` declaration of `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *aTextFieldOnTheMainView;`. This causes the deallocation of the property when the flipsideview comes onto the screen.

hope this helps

Comment: How do I change it so that it stays allocated when flipsideview comes in?  Would I change `weak` to `strong`?

Comment: Actually, just tried changing `weak` to `strong` and I still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick. For more info check out this question [link!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912555/weak-and-strong-property-setter-attributes-in-objective-c)

Comment: Except that didn't do it, sorry.

Comment: And is this property connected to a textfield on the IB?

Comment: It is a property connected to a textfield on the Main view.  What's the IB?

Comment: IB is Interface Builder (for storyboards or .xib) When your main view is no longer the view on screen, does the textField get deallocated?

Comment: Ah yeah, then yes, it is connected to the interface builder (I think).  This would involve control-dragging the field to the .h file, right?

Comment: And how do I tell if the textField gets deallocated?

Comment: well you would know if you manually deallocated it or if the main view gets deallocated. Thus causing the subviews to deallocate

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I guess.  I didn't manually deallocate anything, so it must be happening automatically somewhere.  I haven't changed much from the default settings, so it must be something that's automatically set from the beginning.  Why would the main view get deallocated when the flipside view comes into play?

Comment: use the delegate methods used to dismiss the flipside view controller to pass the text along (NSString).

Comment: I haven't found a good explanation of the delegate method yet.  It all goes over my head.  Sorry!